# Angular set error message ngIf Else stattement

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, object

Hi I've an array which I'm looping and displaying the id as link

```
errMsg: string
const group = [
    {
        "name": "TSPM Process Connector Validation",
        "values": [
            {
                "id": "10007017",
                "url": "http://www.aol.com",
                "component": "TSPM Process Connector Validation",
                "requestSentStatus": 1,
                "responseReceivedStatus": 1
            },
            {
                "id": "10007016",
                "url": "http://msn.com",
                "component": "TSPM Process Connector Validation",
                "requestSentStatus": 1,
                "responseReceivedStatus": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "TSPM Application Mapping Validation",
        "values": [
            {
                "component": "TSPM Application Mapping Validation",
                "requestSentStatus": 1,
                "responseReceivedStatus": 0
            },
            {
                "component": "TSPM Application Mapping Validation",
                "requestSentStatus": 1,
                "responseReceivedStatus": 0
            }
        ]
    }
]

  getStatusMessage(group) {
    if (group) {
        for (const mappedObj of group.values) {
          if (mappedObj.requestSentStatus === null || mappedObj.requestSentStatus === undefined) {
            this.errMsg = 'Enqueued for pickup and processing.'
          } else if (mappedObj.requestSentStatus === 0 ){
            this.errMsg = 'Failure sending data to CM.';
          } else if (mappedObj.requestSentStatus === 1) {
            if (mappedObj.responseReceivedStatus === null || mappedObj.responseReceivedStatus === undefined) {
              this.errMsg = 'CR generation awaited from CM.'
            } else if (mappedObj.responseReceivedStatus === 0) {
              this.errMsg = 'CR generation failed at CM.'
            } else if (mappedObj.responseReceivedStatus === 1) {
              this.errMsg = '';
            }
            console.log('errorMessage', this.errMsg);
          }
        }
     }
  }
```

HTML

```
 <ol class="lmn-list-group lmn-list-group-initial">
     <ng-container *ngFor="let value of group.values">
             <li class="lmn-list-group-item" *ngIf="value.id; else crCreationFailTmp">
                  <a [href]="value.url" target="_blank" [mtTooltip]="value.id" placement="top">
                                      {{ value.id}}
                  </a>
             </li>
      <div class="lmn-pb-2 lmn-font-size-xs bfaText">{{ value.name }}</div>
    </ng-container>
 </ol>
 <ng-template #crCreationFailTmp>
       <li class="lmn-list-group-item lmn-pl-3 lmn-text-danger">{{errMsg}}</li>  
 </ng-template>
```

I'm displaying ID with the link of url, so if the id is not present instead I want to display the message based on the condition mentioned in function getStatusMessage.
So basically I'm checking multiple conditions in order to show different error messages as per the requestSentStatus & responseReceivedStatus value. SO I need to display error message for each value object if condition not met.
I'm doing that but for error message I just see it empty without error message not sure why. What wrong am i doing?

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the getStatusMessage() function according to the code snippets that you have provided.